# Fake files created when testing Storage

Tags: laravel

I have a class for testing upload functionality:

```
class FileUploadTest extends TestCase
{

    protected $currentDate;
    protected $filename;

    public function setUp() {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->currentDate = now()->toDateString();
        $this->filename = str_random(20) . '.jpg';
        Storage::fake('uploads');
    }

    /** @test */
    public function test_a_user_can_upload_a_file() {
        $res = $this->json('POST', '/files', [
            'file' => UploadedFile::fake()->image($this->filename)
        ]);
        $content = $res->decodeResponseJson();

        Storage::assertExists($content['path']);
    }

...
}
```

`$content['path']` has this kind of format: `'uploads/2018-06-06/filename.ext'`

I see that after each test, fake files are created in the `storage/app` folder. How do I stop this?

Comment: You don't, you delete them in `tearDown()`

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56678482/1575353) has a good explanation about cleaning up the files after the test - as @Ohgodwhy suggests, I have put that in my `tearDown` method.