# Laravel Testing with storage fake

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, faker

I have developed a function to download CSV file which generated based on the database.
I have created testing for this and working fine for me. but the problem is the file is not getting deleted after completing the test run.

**Question**. Will this file created using storage fake got deleted automatically once the test completely run? if yes it is not deleted for me. please look into my test function.

```
/*Test file*/
public function testAmazonDailyPendingStatusReport(){
    //creating factories    
    Storage::fake('reportslocal');  
    $dailyStatus = new DailyStatus(
       new FileWriter(),
       new Filesystem(),
       Storage::disk('reportslocal')
   );
   $fileExported = $dailyStatus->export();
   //continuing assertions
}

/*export function*/
public function export(){
     //fetch data from database.
     //create file using SplFileObject
     //writing files into it.
     //storing to 'reportslocal' path
     //sending email to client with attached this file
}
```

If the file not deleted automatically, what should I do? or can I use `Storage::disk('reportslocal')->delete($fileExported)` in my test function
. Is this a proper way?

What is the best assertion to be checked here?
I have checked, the file existence, column number, column header sequence, and value, check the contents of the file. is there anything I missed?

Please help me to do this(Priority is the storage::fake() issue.).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try using the unlink function of php, just pass exact path to your file to unlink function to delete the file.

Comment: my question was will the file got deleted automatically? if yes, what I missed in my function. If no, then what is the exact use of storage::fake? and I am using laravel 5.7

Comment: By default, the fake method will delete all files in its temporary directory. If you would like to keep these files, you may use the "persistentFake" method instead.

Comment: But, the file is not deleting for me. can you please help me to find out where I made mistake?

Comment: +1 for this question. The files are left in the directory `storage/framework/testing/disks/[fakediskname]`. It's not a huge problem necessarily as you can ignore the files and they're overwritten without issue when rerunning the tests. But you'd expect the files to be cleaned up.

Answer (score 20):

#### Why `Storage::fake()`

`Storage::fake()` is used to setup a directory on your local disk for your test suite to use. This helps keep you from modifying your actual defined storage disks.

If, for example, your code is using the `s3` disk, where all operations will be hitting your configured AWS s3 bucket, you can call `Storage::fake('s3')`, and it will swap out your s3 cloud configuration with a simple local disk without having to modify the code you're testing at all.

#### Main Question

Now, every time you call `Storage::fake('reportslocal')`, it will clear out the files in the defined directory when that method is called. However, there is nothing that automatically clears out the files again once the test is complete.

If you want to empty out the directory after your test is complete, you have a couple options.

1. you can just call `Storage::fake('reportslocal')` again at the end of your test. That'll run the code to clear out the fake disk.
2. you can call the code to manually clear out your fake disk yourself:

   ```
   (new Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem)->cleanDirectory(Storage::disk('reportslocal')->path(''))
   ```

   Careful here! If you run the above command, but forgot to fake your disk first, you'll empty out your real disk. So, really, you'd be safer just to call `Storage::fake('reportslocal')` a second time at the end of your test.

Answer (score 2):

Later edit:

Please read the following comment before you want to test s3 upload behavior.
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/how-do-you-testing-laravel-filesystem-with-aws?page=1&replyId=455104

---

As @Simon pointed out in a comment and @patricus in response, there are two points to keep in mind:

1. `Storage::fake()` will actually write files to:

`<ROOT>/storage/framework/testing/disks/local`

(or, if we place a name like `Storage::fake('public')`, then it will place the files in `<ROOT>/storage/framework/testing/disks/public`

Even if we set 's3' as a parameter, the files will still be written locally to `<ROOT>/storage/framework/testing/disks/s3`, so it doesn't help to see if the connection to s3 works and if the files are actually written in s3.

2. If we want to see that the s3 part really works, then we don't have to use `fake()` but build the `Storage` with the necessary s3 configuration. It will write files to s3. At the end of the test files may be deleted.
   Ex:

##### !!! The following method will overwrite any existing files on your s3 disk IF files name/path are the same with those created during the tests.

```php
    $storage = Storage::build(config('filesystems.disks.s3'));
    $storage->put('path/to/file.ext', 'content');
```

So, to be sure that it will not overwrite any existent file in your real s3,  **I recommend to have another bucket only for testing** . This separate s3 will also help you if have complex flows in the application (the above code Storage::build will help only in the test function) and you can set s3 as default driver and tests will run with that configuration.